# PHP loops works on localhost but on server

Tags: php, loops, server, localhost

I have a weird problem. I read all related topic but there was no any solution for me. There are bunch of php codes on my project and all work perfectly but that one :

```
<?php
    require("connection.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mrf WHERE completed=0 AND archive IS NULL ORDER BY projectname";
    $get = $db->prepare($query);
    $get->execute();
    if ($get->rowCount()!=0){
    foreach ($get as $res) {
      '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="font-weight-bold">Product(s) : </span>';
      $pieces = explode(",", $res['products']);
      $pieces_count = count($pieces);
      for ($i=0; $i <= $pieces_count -1 ; $i++) { 
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE id = :id";
        $get2 = $db->prepare($query2);
        $get2->bindValue(":id",$pieces[$i]);
        $get2->execute();
        if ($get2->rowCount()!=0){
          foreach ($get2 as $res2) {
            echo $res2['name'].'<b>/</b>';
          }
       }
    }       
    echo '</li>';
```

It works localhost perfectly but on server the result is empty.

- I have checked the error(s)

  ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ```

But there is no any error. Also If there had been an error, I would have seen it on localhost, because error_reporting works on localhost as well as on live server.

- I checked typos, no any typo
- Checked cpanel everything related to PHP. All is OK. By the way php ver is 5.6
- Any idea??

-----------------------------------**RESULT**----------------------------

-I have checked all codes again and didn't find any error.
-I contacted my hosting company. They said my server has reached RLimitMEM (don't know what it is) So they increased my RlimitMEM value.
- I amnot satisfied with hosting company's answer but the code is working now.
- I appreciate for all answers and advices.

Comment: Did you update your database info..?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code, its a miracle it worked on localhost with that code.

Comment: have you tried using `SELECT * FROM mrf WHERE completed='0' AND archive IS NULL ORDER BY projectname` sometimes the single quote is needed

Comment: It seems likely that your server database is missing some records from `mrf`. Also, are you sure you copy-pasted this line correctly? `<li class="list-group-item"><span class="font-weight-bold">Product(s) : </span>';`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with the following and check

```
<?php
require("connection.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM mrf WHERE completed=0 AND archive IS NULL ORDER BY projectname";
$get = $db->prepare($query);
$get->execute();
if ($get->rowCount()!=0){
foreach ($get as $res) { ?>
  '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="font-weight-bold">Product(s) : 
</span>';
  <?php 
  $pieces = explode(",", $res['products']);
  $pieces_count = count($pieces);
  for ($i=0; $i <= $pieces_count -1 ; $i++) { 
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE id = :id";
    $get2 = $db->prepare($query2);
    $get2->bindValue(":id",$pieces[$i]);
    $get2->execute();
    if ($get2->rowCount()!=0){
      foreach ($get2 as $res2) {
        echo $res2['name'].'<b>/</b>';
      }
    }
  }
  echo '</li>';
 }
}
```

You have not closed the PHP, closing curly braces were not there...

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing it out:

```
foreach ($get as $res) {
  '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="font-weight-bold">Product(s) : </span>';
```

Missing something there, no?

```
foreach ($get as $res) {
  echo '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="font-weight-bold">Product(s) : </span>';
```

Sometimes it's the simple things.

Of note is PHP is perfectly fine with just having a useless string defined:

```
'foo';
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/976e3633048fd5755f07b7c01736d09a3c2b635b)

It won't complain about that.  For other languages this may be an issue, but PHP is very fault tolerant (sometimes to much so).

**PS** `require("connection.php");` is not a function, while it will work with the `()` it's considered a bad practice.  Instead `require "connection.php";` works fine.  This helps to differentiate it from a function when you glance at the code.

You should also move this around a bit:

```
foreach ($get as $res) {   
   //...
  for ($i=0; $i <= $pieces_count -1 ; $i++) { 
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE id = :id";
    $get2 = $db->prepare($query2);
    $get2->bindValue(":id",$pieces[$i]);
    $get2->execute();
```

And do it like this:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE id = :id";
$get2 = $db->prepare($query2);

foreach ($get as $res) {   
   //...
  for ($i=0; $i <= $pieces_count -1 ; $i++) { 
     $get2->execute(['id'=>$pieces[$i]]); //instead of binding, you can just do it in execute too
```

And do the Prepare outside of the loop, this will improve performance in most cases.  Every time you do a Prepare the DB is used to compile the query instructions, then when you execute it only the data is sent. This is how they defeat SQl Injection, because the SQL and the DATA are handled separately.

So by preparing it within the Loop you are asking the DB for unnecessary work.  The format of the SQL does not change per/loop only the data does. Therefor, there is only the need to `execute` the query for each iteration.

**Lastly:**

Your missing two closing `}}` in your code for the question.  Make sure to fix those syntax errors.  I suspect they are just a omission in the question as you stated the code works locally.

Comment: This is probably the correct solution. The string before was just unused, and not displayed.

Comment: Still the if and foreach curly braces not closed, this is not a complete solution

Comment: @RakeshJakhar the OP did not post entire `if` block. Your solution would be incorrect HTML as you have a foreach loop opening many `<li>` tags and only closing one; the last one.

Comment: @Ice76he mentioned "t works localhost perfectly but on server the result is empty.", this means the the code he posted is working on localhost, than entire code should be corrected

Comment: It's very easy when posting a question to omit the last two `}}`. This `works localhost perfectly` also suggest a simple typo in the question - also I figured that it was covered well enough in the comments.  But I did an update anyway.  In anycase that was not the source of this issue, forgetting to output it was, as I put in the answer.  The rest is probably simple typographical error when posting the question.

Comment: I really appreciate guys. You are like fortuneteller :) As @Rakesh said, I did not post my all codes. Just posted relevant part. Therefore as if there are some mistakes. But actual code doesn't have any syntax error. Otherwise it wouldn't have worked on localhost. Anyway I am gonna update the result.